# Фонетична транскрипція слова "п'ятдесят"?

Tags: фонетика, spelling

[[пйа**тд**еис`а́т]](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BF'%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82) - на сайті Горох зазначено, що звук [т] вимовляється.

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) ж говорить, що слово п'ятдесят вимовляється без звука [т]: [пйадеис'а́т]

На інших сайтах ще можна знайти таку транскрипцію, де звук [д] є подовженим: [пйад:еис'а́т]

То як усе ж таки правильно транскрибувати це слово? І чи аналогічним чином транскрибуються літери "тд" в наступних словах: ар**тд**иректор, ве**тд**опомога, дев'я**тд**есят, двохсо**тд**оларовий, компак**тд**иск, куль**тд**іяч, охма**тд**и́т, полі**тд**іяч, хо**тд**ог?

Answer (score 2):

Орфоепічний словник Погрібного (1984р) подає це та похідні слова з подовженим звуком д
[image]

Comment: Дякую! Скажіть, будь ласка, на скільки можна довіряти Орфоепічному словнику Погрібного? Він аж 1984 року, тому в мене виникає насторога до його актуальності та чинності.